# List each sub-directory present in path string (ksh)

Tags: path, ksh

I'm trying to list every sub-directory or file present in a path.

For example, to this path:

```
/path/to/some/place
```

I want this output:

```
/path
/path/to
/path/to/some
/path/to/some/place
```

Answer (score 0):

When the dirs are without spaces, you could do

```
subpath=""
for dir in $(echo "/path/to/some/place" | tr "/" " " ); do 
   subpath+="/${dir}" 
   echo "$subpath"
done

/path
/path/to
/path/to/some
/path/to/some/place
```

When you have more complicated dirnames (and always assume you have), you need another solution.

```
myvar="/path/to/some/place"
IFS=/ read -ra d <<< "$myvar"
for dir in ${d[@]}; do
   subpath+="/${dir}";
   echo "${subpath}"
done
```